Mexico custom, electronic device limit, and an old Kindle
I'm going to Mexico City (from US, tourism visit). I'm planning to bring my old "kindle keyboard" and my android tablet. Do I have to pay tax for one of them since (if I'm not mistaken) you can only bring 1 tablet?
https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/montreal/index.php/en/foreigners/services-foreigners/407-what-objects-can-i-bring-in-my-luggage-to-mexico

What makes you think you can only bring one tablet?

Mexican consulate website.

https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/montreal/index.php/en/foreigners/services-foreigners/407-what-objects-can-i-bring-in-my-luggage-to-mexico

@JoseMulia from the list on that page I would have thought that an e-reader and a tablet would be considered under the "three cellphones or other wireless devices"

I have entered Mexico by air and land six or eight times in the past ten years, and have never had my computers(s) or device(s) even noticed by Mexican Customs.

That’s a pretty arbitrary and very outdated list. It doesn’t even include your clothes or toiletries…

I just got back from Mexico City. They checked my bag, asked me to pull out my electronics from my duffle bag. They let me pass through. I don't think they cared much.
